# Not able to upload the edited value of textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I am using the below code for the textfield in flutter, `itemName` value is retrieved from the firestore  database, and `controlleritemName` is assigned to the same textfield, when the field is edited and then I used `controlleritemName.text` to upload the edited field to firestore database then it does not load the page and giving the error of

> 'initialValue== null||controller == null: is not true.'

How should I correct it?

```
TextFormField(initialValue: itemName,
              controller: controlleritemName,
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use initial value and controller at the same time, you should use one of them.
So if you want to use the controller, you can assign the initial value of the textfield in the controller.
For example

```
controlleritemName = TextEditingController(text: {your initial value});
```

Then your textfield

```
TextFormField(
     controller: controlleritemName,
)
```